# SQLite Full Text Search Queries With Hyphens

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I have been using SQLite (3) for a small website. Recently, I have discovered SQLite's full text search (FTS) capability and leveraged it for a simple search feature. However, a user inadvertently discovered that a hyphen ('-') in the search string does the wrong thing. It seems to indicate that the token immediately following should be excluded. In fact, when I change the hyphen to a plus or a space, it does work.

**My questions: 1) Am I correct in this analysis?** I read the [SQLite documentation regarding the FTS feature](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) and found no discussion about this. **2) How should I mitigate this?** Manually replace hyphens before passing them to SQLite?

A small, concrete example of what I'm seeing:

```
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table USING fts4
   ...> ( content TEXT );

sqlite> INSERT INTO fts_table VALUES ("Title: F-1 Race (Game Boy)");
sqlite> INSERT INTO fts_table VALUES ("Title: F-Zero (SNES)");
sqlite> INSERT INTO fts_table VALUES ("Title: F-15 Strike Eagle II (Genesis)");

sqlite> SELECT * FROM fts_table;
Title: F-1 Race (Game Boy)
Title: F-Zero (SNES)
Title: F-15 Strike Eagle II (Genesis)
```

*(This database is related to old video games, as you might have guessed.)*

So the website takes the search string from the user and plugs it into a SELECT statement using the MATCH operator. For the search string 'f-zero', the relevant SQL becomes:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE content MATCH 'f-zero';
Title: F-1 Race (Game Boy)
Title: F-15 Strike Eagle II (Genesis)
```

I.e., it doesn't match the title 'F-Zero'. However, the string 'f+zero' returns the right thing:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE content MATCH 'f+zero';
Title: F-Zero (SNES)
```

Again, I suppose I could substitute '+' or a space for '-' before sending the string to SQLite, but that doesn't really feel like the right solution.

Comment: [Set Operations Using The Standard Query Syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found in the doc :

```
The NOT operator (or, if using the standard syntax, a unary "-" operator)
```

So they are the same, and the example :

```
-- Query for all documents that contain the term "database", but do not contain
-- the term "sqlite". Document 1 is the only document that matches this criteria.
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'database NOT sqlite';
```

That's the same as :

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'database -sqlite';
```

In your case your must use the Phrase queries, like this :

```
SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE content MATCH '"f-zero"';
```

Comment: Thanks. I had read about phrase queries but I didn't realize that that's what I needed. In my PHP script, I wrapped my query string variable in quotes and solved the problem.

Comment: I was running blind, until I noticed that that the key is to use double quotes within single quotes to make it work. Thanks for that.